# tensorflow.python.framework.errors_impl.NotFoundError: NewRandomAccessFile failed to Create/Open: ..\vocab

Tags: python, tensorflow

I use tensorflow1.0 python3.5.2 in windows platform,used tensorflow cnn example to do sentiment analysis,but have an error:tensorflow.python.framework.errors_impl.NotFoundError: NewRandomAccessFile failed to Create/Open: ..\vocab: ϵͳ\udcd5Ҳ\udcbb\udcb5\udcbdָ\udcb6\udca8\udcb5\udcc4\udcceļ\udcfe\udca1\udca3
I couldn't find answer,the github address is
https://github.com/dennybritz/cnn-text-classification-tf

Answer (score 0):

I have met this problem before.You can try to run the program on Linux with python2.7.